# ng-repeat show index of object in array in the html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i want have this array:

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

and i want show the data and the index in the html, using angular:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data">
  <p> index of {{ data }}: {{ something here }} </p>
</div>
```

and the output would be

```
<div>
  <p> index of 1: 0 </p>
  <p> index of 2: 1 </p>
  <p> index of 3: 2 </p>
  <p> index of 4: 3 </p>
  <p> index of 5: 4 </p>
</div>
```

Possible?

Comment: put {{$index}} in place of {{ something here }}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`$index`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data">
    <p> index of {{ data }}: {{ $index }} </p>
</div>
```